# Returning a list of numbers from a loop inside a function

Tags: objective-c, c

Maybe it is a stupid question but now I learn Objective C and I tried to extend my knowldge, learning by mistakes.

So I tried to adapt the Sieve of Erastosthenes to be a function. I understand  that when   a function received an result , that determines function to stop.

I'm curious if it is a way to adapt the code  that return i to send the list of all numbers  as appears in  NSLog(@" Prime number %i", i); In a way to execute function multiple times

Thanks

My code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int erathos (int n)
{


 int i, prime, multiple, P[n];

  for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
   {
    P[i] = 1;
   }

for (prime = 2; prime <= n; ++prime)
{
    if (P[prime])

    for (multiple = 2 * prime; multiple <= n; multiple += prime)
    {


        if (P[multiple]) {

            P[multiple] = 0;

      } 
   }
}

for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
 {
    if (P[i])
     NSLog(@" Prime number %i", i);

 }
 return i;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   @autoreleasepool {
       int erathos (int n); 
       NSLog(@"Erathos %i", erathos (150));  
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you fix the formatting/indenting?

Comment: What is the type of the function you want? Something like `NSArray* erathos(int n);`? Where the return return value is an array of `NSNumbers` wrapping `int`s that are prime?

Comment: i need a simple c array .

Comment: I'd recommend using a NSArray if you're trying to learn Objective-C, it's more idiomatic for the language. If you want to return a C array, you need to worry about who owns the memory (should the caller pass it in as a buffer? should the function `malloc` it and leave it up to the callee to `free` it?).

Comment: You are right.Maybe an NSArray with list of i numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSArray` data type is the basic array type in Objective-C. The `NSMutableArray` represents the mutable array type. Arrays can only store objects, not primitive types such as `int`, so the items need to be converted to `NSNumber` objects before being added to the array.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSArray* erathos (int n){
    int i, prime, multiple, P[n];
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        P[i] = 1;
    }

    for (prime = 2; prime <= n; ++prime) {
        if (P[prime]) {
            for (multiple = 2 * prime; multiple <= n; multiple += prime) {
                if (P[multiple]) {
                    P[multiple] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (P[i]) {
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }
    }
    return array;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // To format any object, use the '@' type specifier.
        NSLog(@"Erathos %@", erathos (150));  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the function declaration should look like:

```
NSArray* erathos(int n);
```

Note that NSArray is *immutable*, this means that once it has been created you cannot change it. If you want to add values, you needs its mutable subclass, NSMutableArray.

Create an empty NSMutableArray with:

```
NSMutableArray *primesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

To add integers to it, use

```
[primesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

Then to return an immutable copy of it, use:

```
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:primesArray];
```

Note that you could just return the NSMutableArray, but then a callee could change it which might be undesirable.

Both the mutable array and the immutable copy are autoreleased, so they will be freed when the current autoreleasepool is drained. To keep hold of them, you need to retain them like this:

```
[myObject retain];
```

To print all primes, you can use a foreach construct:

```
for (NSNumber *n in primesArray) {
  NSLog(@"Prime number: %i", [n intValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapt Krumelur solution adding a new NSArray parameter . That gives the possibility to use every  object from NSArray's index.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSArray* erathos ( NSMutableArray* array, int n){
int i, prime, multiple, P[n];
for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    P[i] = 1;
}

for (prime = 2; prime <= n; ++prime) {
    if (P[prime]) {
        for (multiple = 2 * prime; multiple <= n; multiple += prime) {
            if (P[multiple]) {
                P[multiple] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (P[i]) {
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}
return array;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

     NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array];


     NSLog(@"Erathos %@", erathos (myArray,150));

     NSLog(@"myArray objectAtIndex 5 is is %@", [myArray objectAtIndex: 5]);






}
return 0;
}
```